# How to Insert a Variable Number of Records into an Access Table Based on a Fields Value

Tags: sql, ms-access, automation, vba, sql-insert

I have an Access Table with the following columns: WeeklyID(PrimaryKey), CampaignID(Foreignkey), WeekEnded(Date Field), Duration(Number Field).

I want to automatically add X number of records to the table, where X is the number stored in the Duration field. I want the added records to have the same CampaignID as the original record. So the automated process would be satisfied when the count of the records with one specific CampaignID was equal to the Duration number.

If anyone could provide assistance on how to accomplish this, it would be much appreciated. If you need any further info, please ask!

Comment: Why do you need these records? When do you want them to be added?

Comment: Are you using the target table as the source also? Do you plan to run your code more than once?

Comment: The target table is also the source. However, the duration value is also tied to the foreign key i.e. it's also stored and can be pulled from another table if using the target as the source creates extra issues. I plan on calling on the code automatically to append the extra records each time a new record is added to the table.

Comment: @BitAccesser 
I need these records to add data on the weekly level for campaigns, the table has more columns than simply the 4 I mentioned, but those are the only ones that matter for my question.

Comment: I did some code for another person to do something similar. How mant total records do you ever expect in that table? If millions, you need an approach that doesn't touch every record when adding one new record. I suggest code that would set the initial table and could be run in the future to validate things are still ok, then code just to add the required records for a new record. How good are your VBA skills?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn We won't sniff 7 digits. We're only talking tens of thousands when all is said and done. My VBA is very weak, but as my username suggests I am trying to learn, and should be capable of adapting exisitng code to fit my exact circumtance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. Note that I planned for a scenario where someone changes the duration -- after adding the records.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim dbs     As DAO.Database
Dim rs      As DAO.recordSet
Dim rsOT    As DAO.recordSet

Function Create_New_Rows()
Dim strSQL          As String
Dim i               As Integer
Dim iAdd            As Integer
Dim iDuration       As Integer
Dim lCampaignID     As Long


    On Error GoTo Error_trap

    Set dbs = CurrentDb

    strSQL = "SELECT Count(Campaign.WeeklyID) AS NbrRecs, First(Campaign.Duration) AS Duration, Campaign.CampaignID " & _
                "FROM Campaign " & _
                "GROUP BY Campaign.CampaignID;"
    Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    Set rsOT = dbs.OpenRecordset("Campaign")
    If rs.EOF Then
        MsgBox "No records found!", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "No Records"
        GoTo Exit_Code
    Else
        rs.MoveFirst
    End If

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        Debug.Print "Campaign: " & rs!CampaignID & vbTab & "Duration: " & rs!Duration & vbTab & "# Recs: " & rs!NbrRecs
        iDuration = rs!Duration
        lCampaignID = rs!CampaignID


        ' Check if already have correct number of records for this ID
        If iDuration = rs!NbrRecs Then
            ' Do nothing... counts are good
        ElseIf iDuration < rs!NbrRecs Then
            MsgBox "Add code to resolve too many records for Campaign: " & lCampaignID & vbCrLf & _
                "Duration: " & iDuration & vbCrLf & _
                "Records: " & rs!NbrRecs, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Too many records already!"
        Else
            ' Finally, Duration is less than existing records... time to add...
            iAdd = iDuration - rs!NbrRecs
            Do
                If iAdd > 0 Then
                    ' Add new record
                    Add_Records lCampaignID
                    iAdd = iAdd - 1
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

Exit_Code:
    If Not rs Is Nothing Then
        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
    End If
    If Not rsOT Is Nothing Then
        rsOT.Close
        Set rsOT = Nothing
    End If
    dbs.Close
    Set dbs = Nothing

    MsgBox "Finished"

    Exit Function
Error_trap:
    Debug.Print Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "In:   Create_New_Rows"
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "In: Create_New_Rows"
    Resume Exit_Code
    Resume
End Function

Function Add_Records(lCampID As Long)
    With rsOT
        .AddNew
        !CampaignID = lCampID
        ' Add code if you want to populate other fields...
        .Update
        'Debug.Print "Added rec for CampaingID: " & lCampID
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! I am going to try to adapt this to my needs over the next couple days. My lack of VBA knowledge might make it a slow process for me, so I may follow up with some questions a bit down the line.

Comment: In this snippet:

`If iAdd > 0 Then

' Add new record

Add_Records lCampaign

iAdd = iAdd - 1`

Gets the ByRef Argument Type Mismatch error and highlights "lCampaign". Any thoughts on what's going wrong here?

Comment: Assumed the CampaignID was a Long Integer, thus the variable and the argument in the called subroutine will need to change to your datatype. For example, if it's a string, change 'lCampID As Long' to '... String' and change 'lCampaignID as Long' to '... String'  (Plus any other datatype changes that are necessary.

Comment: Thanks again Wayne. I changed the variable type when you declared your variables for the first function, Create_New_Rows, but forgot to do the same for the second, Add_Records. Now that I changed both, it seems to be working!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this function to have lngCount as a fixed value:

```
Public Sub CopyEmptyRecords()

  Dim rstSource   As DAO.Recordset
  Dim rstInsert   As DAO.Recordset
  Dim fld         As DAO.Field
  Dim strSQL      As String
  Dim lngLoop     As Long
  Dim lngCount    As Long
  Dim booCopy     As Boolean

  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblStats"
  Set rstSource = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

  strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tblStatsNull"
  Set rstInsert = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

  With rstSource
    .MoveLast
    .MoveFirst
    lngCount = .RecordCount            ' Set to fixed value of 7.
    For lngLoop = 1 To lngCount
      With rstInsert
        booCopy = False
        .AddNew
          For Each fld In rstSource.Fields
            With fld
              If .Attributes And dbAutoIncrField Then
                ' Skip Autonumber or GUID field.
              Else
                ' Copy field content.
                rstInsert.Fields(.Name).Value = .Value
                If Len(Trim(Nz(.Value, vbNullString))) = 0 Then
                  booCopy = True
                End If
              End If
            End With
          Next
        If booCopy = True Then
          .Update
        Else
          .CancelUpdate
        End If
      End With
      .MoveNext
    Next
    rstInsert.Close
    .Close
  End With

  Set rstInsert = Nothing
  Set rstSource = Nothing

End Sub
```